# Link detector using discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have created link detector, it works well but I want to disable this command for single guilds. I know I should use json file but I honestly don't know how to use it in this case here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "-", intents = intents)
anti_link == 'off'

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    global anti_link
    if 'https://' in message.content:
        if anti_link == 'on':
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("Links are not allowed here.")
            await client.process_commands(message)

@client.command(name="antilink", aliases=["anti link"])
async def anti_link(ctx):
    global anti_link
    if anti_link == 'off':
        anti_link = 'on'
        await ctx.send('Links Detector has been Enabled.')
        return anti_link
    else:
        anti_link = 'off'
        await ctx.send('Links Detector has been Disabled.')
        return anti_link
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a database, It's almost impossible to store all of that data in variables if you have many guilds. So, Since you don't know about `JSON` files **in your case**. This tutorial can teach you the basics so you can work with it.

### Working with JSON in Python

Before I go into python, Let me tell you the basic structure of JSON is like this.

```json
{
    "key" : "value"
}
```

More like a Python dictionary. So We will use a module called `json` that **ships with python** so you will not need to do `pip install json` or any thing like that. This module helps us works with JSON easily.

`json` module can change a Python dictionary into a JSON file format like there are some boolean that are different in Python and JSON. For example, `True` is `true` in JSON (with small 't'), `False` is `false` and `None` is `null`. So basically JSON module changes these booleans so that it can be dumped into JSON.

With that being a intro to `json` module let me show you how to use it in your code;

Firstly create a new JSON file in bot directory and name it anything. Let's say `antilink.json` And in that file, put `{}` (curly brackets) This is important or you will get an error.

In this file we will store our **each** guild's toggles for that certain feature.

Import JSON module into your bot file at the top (Again, You don't have to install `json` module it ships with Python, If you have Python, You have json module)

```py
import json
```

So, Now in your antilink command that changes the guild's toggle;

```py
@client.command(name="antilink", aliases=["anti link"])
async def anti_link(ctx):
    try:
        with open("antilink.json", "r") as f: # Opening JSON file in variable "f"
            antilink= json.load(f) # Parsing it to a Python dictionary.
        anti_link= antilink[str(ctx.guild.id)] # Getting the Guild's Value via it's value.

    except KeyError: # If guild toggle isnt in JSON file, Adding it.
        antilink[str(ctx.guild.id)] = "on"
        with open("antilink.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(antilink, f, indent=4) # Writing the changes to JSON


    if anti_link == 'off':
        anti_link = 'on'
        with open("antilink.json", "r") as f:
            antilink= json.load(f)
            # print(antilink) # Uncomment this to see how JSON file will look after loading.
        antilink[str(ctx.guild.id)] = anti_link # setting the guild toggle to 'on'
        
        with open("antilink.json", "w") as f: # Opening the JSON file but with write mode so we can dump the changes
            json.dump(antilink, f, indent=4) # Finally Dumping the changes.

        await ctx.send('Links Detector has been Enabled.')
        
    else:
        """Doing the same thing here"""
        anti_link = 'off'
        with open("antilink.json", "r") as f:
            antilink= json.load(f)
            
        antilink[str(ctx.guild.id)] = anti_link # setting the guild toggle to 'off'
        
        with open("antilink.json", "w") as f: # Opening the JSON file but with write mode so we can dump the changes
            json.dump(antilink, f, indent=4) # Finally Dumping the changes.
```

This is the command, Now we have to check that if toggle is disabled or enabled in our `on_message` event.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'https://' in message.content:
        try:
            with open("antilink.json", "r") as f: # Opening JSON file in variable "f"
                antilink= json.load(f) # Parsing it to a Python dictionary.
            anti_link= antilink[str(ctx.guild.id)] # Getting the Guild's Value via it's value.

        except KeyError: # If guild toggle isnt in JSON file, Adding it.
            anti_link = "off"
            antilink[str(ctx.guild.id)] = anti_link
            with open("antilink.json", "w") as f:
                 json.dump(antilink, f, indent=4) # Writing the changes to JSON
        
        if anti_link == 'on':
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("Links are not allowed here.")
        else: # if anti_link is off then do nothing.
            return

        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Please read more about the JSON module from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)